# Parse XML with metadata and data rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have to parse xml file with metadata and data in rows. How can I link the fields in metadata and fields in the row using javascript.

```html
  
  <dataset>
    <metadata>
      <item name="Number" type="xs:string" length="30" />
      <item name="Sex" type="xs:string" length="2" />
      <item name="Birth Date" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Age" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Name" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Type" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Reg Start" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Reg End" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Term Code" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Start" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="End" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Member Days" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Reason Code" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Base Rate" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Comp Care" type="xs:string" length="162" />
      <item name="Complex Adjmt" type="xs:string" length="162" />
    </metadata>
    <data>
      <row>
        <value>599420000</value>
        <value>M</value>
        <value>2005-10-22</value>
        <value>5</value>
        <value>ALAS, AMEXXRA</value>
        <value></value>
        <value>2008-01-13</value>
        <value>2015-08-26</value>
        <value>91</value>
        <value>2015-08-27</value>
        <value>2015-08-31</value>
        <value>5</value>
        <value></value>
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value>-0.22</value>
        <value xs:nil="true" />
      </row>
    </data>
 </dataset>
```

Can ajax or jquery be used to parse it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you by chance try googling for an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use `jQuery` to parse it.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

> `jQuery.parseXML` uses the native parsing function of the browser to
>   create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to
>   `jQuery` to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and
>   manipulated.